# Linked server anonymous login error

Tags: sql-server, permissions, linked-server, errors, logins

I am trying to access a database in my UAT server through a windows login credential. When I try to access the database, I get the error `Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'` This windows account has sysadmin rights so I am not sure why I can't access it.

I believe that this database is part of a linked server because when I test the connection to the linked server, I get the same anonymous login error. I asked a fellow team member to try to test this connection, and he says his test succeeded with no error. When I change the security property in the linked server to "be made without using a security context" it gives me this error:

```
The OLE DB provider "SQLNxxx" for linked server "xxx" reported an error. Authentication failed.
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "SQLNxxx" for linked server "xxxx".
OLE DB provider "SQLxxxx" for linked server "Mxxxxxx" returned message "Invalid authorization specification". (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)
```

As you can tell from the error above the linked server is a connecting from one SQL Server to another. I have tried to read from tables and views as well and still receive the same anon error.

I have researched multiple days online and could not find a good resolution. Some of the solutions they suggested are to change the security settings but that one did not work.

Please offer me some advice as what I can do to resolve this issue. Thank you in advance.

Comment: "NT AUTHORTY\ANONYMOUS LOGON" when dealing with linked servers is almost always indicative of a Kerberos problem. If so, https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/53454/170408 and https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/198658/170408 are worth looking at.

Comment: Can you tell what option from [step 4 of this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15#to-create-a-linked-server-to-another-instance-of-sql-server-using-sql-server-management-studio) are you using for the linked server?